# Create single WireMockServer object with single port

Tags: wiremock, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, gradle-task, wiremock-standalone, wiremock-record

I am very new to Wire mock and gradle. I am planning to setup by using single WireMockServer object with using 8081 port and its configurable in gradle task.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'com.williamhill.wiremock' version '0.4.1'
    id 'java'
}

wiremock {
    dir "src/test/resources/"
    params "--port=8081"
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    runWithWiremock = true
}
```

test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = GladletaskApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureWireMock
@ActiveProfiles(value = "integration")
public class StudentControllerTest {

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule();

    @Autowired
    public TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockRemoteService();
    }
    @Test
    public void testAllStudents() {
        ResponseEntity<List<Student>> responseEntity = testRestTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8093/all", HttpMethod.GET,null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Student>>(){}
        );
        List<Student> studentList = responseEntity.getBody();
        System.out.println("StudentList--->" + studentList.size());
    }

    private void mockRemoteService() {
        stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/all-students"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBodyFile("response.json")
                ));
    }
}
```

Now target is i have 8081 server up only once and run all the test cases and shutdown last

is it possible to do it?
could please provide springboot-wiremock gradle custom task?

Comment: https://github.com/William-Hill-Online/wiremock-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by using the following  :
1) @BeforeClass & @AfterClass start and stop the server.
2) I tried with a created JUnit test suite and @BeforeClass & @AfterClass start and stop the server, here going apply suite level.